# GSON parsing android

Tags: android, json, parsing, null, gson

This is my JSON:

```
{
    "Curs": [
        {
            "ID": "AED",
            "Name": "Dirhamul Emiratelor Arabe",
            "Curs": "0.8503",
            "Multiplier": "1",
            "Data": "2011-02-09"
        },
        {
            "ID": "AUD",
            "Name": "Dolarul australian",
            "Curs": "3.1572",
            "Multiplier": "1",
            "Data": "2011-02-09"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my class:

```
public class Curs {

@SerializedName("ID")
public String id;

@SerializedName("Name")
public String nume;

@SerializedName("Curs")
public  double crs;

@SerializedName("Multiplier")
public  int mult;

@SerializedName("Data")
public  Date data;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getNume() {
    return nume;
}
public void setNume(String nume) {
    this.nume= nume;
}
public void setCrs(double crs) {
    this.crs=crs;
}
public double getCrs(){
    return crs;
}
public void setMult(int mult) {
    this.mult=mult;
}
public int getMult(){
    return mult;
}
public void setData(Date data) {
    this.data=data;
}
public Date getData(){
    return data;
}
```

}

And this is the class that contains my list:

```
public class CursList {

public static List<Curs> listaCurs;

public void setCursList(List <Curs> listaCurs) {
    this.listaCurs = listaCurs;
}

public List<Curs> getCursList() {
    return listaCurs;
}
```

}

I do the parsing like this:

```
Gson gson=new Gson();

    CursList listaCurs=gson.fromJson(Jsonresult,CursList.class);
```

When i access the list i get a null pointer.What am i doing wrong?

Comment: the error occurs when i try to access the list like this: List<Curs> listacurs=listaCurs.listaCurs;
  
  Iterator <Curs> iterator=null;
  iterator=listacurs.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext())
  {
  }

Comment: find if listacurs is null (or if it's the iterator that you got from it)

Answer (score 3):

Found the stupid problem . Json doesn't accept Date format . That was the problem. Thanks to all for the help.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that.  This link might help help writing a custom parser if you need it: http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-type-adapters-for-common-classes-1

Comment: When using a GsonBuilder, you can specify the date format to use with one of the setDateFormat() methods.

Answer (score 1):

Gson is attempting to put the list into a field called "Curs", but there is no such field inside the CursList class.  You should add an annotation in CursList like:

```
public class CursList {
  @SerializedName("Curs")
  public static List<Curs> listaCurs;

  ...
}
```

Comment: I did this but i didn't fixed my error .I hoped this could be the problem .

Answer (score 0):

```
 Gson gson=new Gson();
 Type cursType = new TypeToken<CursList>() { }.getType();
 CursList listaCurs=gson.fromJson(Jsonresult,cursType);
```

Comment: No.This didn't do the trick. Do you have another idea. Maybe i don't access it well .I do like this: List<Curs> listacurs=listaCurs.listaCurs;
  
  Iterator <Curs> iterator=null;
  iterator=listacurs.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext())
  {
  }

Comment: Another idea: add empty constructor for class CursList, and init there new list. public CursList(){listaCurs = new List<Curs>();}